# How to get a nested Firebase array as a collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display only the currently logged-in user's todos. I made it so that when the user logs in, a new doc is made in the 'users' collection. The new user has the same id as the authenticated user's uid. I also implemented a way to push a new todo only into the current user's todos array. Now I just want to display those todos. This is how the data looks:
[image]

Before this, I already implemented a way to add and display the todos regardless of the current user. This is the code for displaying the todos:

```
const todosRef = collection(db, 'todos');
const [newTodos, setNewTodos] = useState([]);

    //get the db data
    useEffect(() => {
        const getTodos = async () => {
            const q = query(todosRef, orderBy("importance", "desc"));
            const data = await getDocs(q);
            setNewTodos(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        }
        getTodos();
    }, [])
```

I just need to modify the todosRef probably, but I don't know how.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have now?  The array in the document should manifest as an array in your snapshot data object.  Please edit the question to explain what specifically is not working the way you expect.  We can't see `setNewTodos` so we can't see if you're doing something wrong in there.

Comment: The problems is that I can't figure out a way to render only user specific todos. The code here only renders todos from a different 'todos' collection. I want to push new todos in the current users todos array. @DougStevenson

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. Kind of.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const [newTodos, setNewTodos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        });

    }, [])

useEffect(() => {
        const getTodos = async () => {
            const todoDoc = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(todoDoc);
            const arrayTodos = docSnap.data().todos;
            setNewTodos(arrayTodos);
        }
        getTodos();
    }, [])
```

The code will display the todos from the current user, but when I refresh the page, the todos are not displayed. They are still in the db, but are not displayed. Why is that?

**Added Note**

When I edit the code and save it the todos show. But when I refresh the page, they are gone.

**Solved kind of**

I think I know why I get this behaviour. When I log in, I set a new user every time into my 'users' collection. I set the users name only as a property. And every time I try to log in, all the todos are deleted, because of that.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

    const addUser = async (username, userid) => {
        await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', userid), {
            name: username
        })
    }

    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(result => {
            const username = result.user.displayName;
            const userId = result.user.uid;
            navigate('/todos');
            addUser(username, userId);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```